# Can't get text info to member variable in form CDialog MFC dialog form

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have small dialog form with Edit Text control:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MyDlg3.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"


// MyDlg3 dialog

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(MyDlg3, CDialog)

MyDlg3::MyDlg3(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(MyDlg3::IDD, pParent)
    , m_edit(_T(""))
{

}

MyDlg3::~MyDlg3()
{
}

void MyDlg3::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_edit);
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyDlg3, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &MyDlg3::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// MyDlg3 message handlers


void MyDlg3::OnBnClickedOk()
{
    txt=m_edit;
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDialog::OnOK();
}
```

And I have simple application that calls this dialog:

```
BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance()
{
    MyDlg3 Dlg3;
    Dlg3.DoModal();
    CString strLine0=Dlg3.txt;
     return true;
}
```

I cant't find why I can't get text that was entered in dialogs Text Control to txt and strLine0 variables.

I found that if I make MyDlg3 from CDialogEx (not from CDialog like it is now) - everything goes fine. Where is problem?

Comment: There should be no problem, CDialogEx inherits from CDialog. Unless some stuff involved in getting data is private. I usually prefer to use DDX_Control and GetWindowText.

Comment: During OnBnClickedOk m_edit is still empty string. I have the same result with DDX_Control and GetWindowText. Why you prefer DDX_Control? It is more easier to write simple string assignment than GetWindowText.

Comment: I'm checking your code but my string stay empty, it's fine instead with DDX_Control and GetWindowText. I prefer this way mostly because we use 3rd party library and setting/getting text is not the only stuff we do on controls; moreover I prefer to have more control on what is going on, but this is a personal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is transferred between the control and the member variable in `DoDataExchange`. `DoDataExchange` is called when you do `CDialog::OnOK` as you can see in the documentation for [`UpdateData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9fb9hww.aspx). By copying the value before then you're not getting any results. You could fix this by moving the copy *after* the call to `OnOK`, or you could skip the copy altogether as suggested by another answer and use the member variable directly.

Answer (score 0):

It's the call to `CDialog::OnOK()` in `MyDlg3::OnBnClickedOk()` that sets up the member variable `m_edit`, so you can write logic like

```
MyDlg3 Dlg3;
Dlg3.DoModal();
CString strLine0 = Dlg3.m_edit;
```

while making sure that `m_edit` is declared as public.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BOOL CPreparationApp::InitInstance()
{
    MyDlg3 Dlg3;
    if(Dlg3.DoModal()==IDOK);
    {
       CString strLine0=Dlg3.txt;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please post some explanation with your code. Try and state what was happening to cause the error, and how you worked around it.